# Can messenger chatbot store messages

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, rights

I am creating a Messenger chatbot and I have a question about law. Can I store communication between user and chatbot on Messenger platform?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an actual programming question.

Comment: For what Facebook generally allows you to do with user data: https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question